# cannot view google documents eventhough iam the owner

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-realtime-api

i am building an application that uploads a doc from my application to drive, then editing via google docs and downloading back to my application. I registered in the google api console using the service account option. now, even after giving permissions in the account, i am not able to view or edit the document. A page is shown with 'you need permission- access denied.' So any idea to turn this around.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using service accounts is not directly owned by the user. It is owned by the app. So if you want to have access on the files, try to insert it to your email using [Permissions.insert](https://developers.google.com/drive/v2/reference/permissions/insert).